# UrlMapping and file name extension

Tags: grails

I have the following url-mapping:

```
name a: "/a/$file" {
    controller = 'attachment'
    action = 'get'
}
```

and I want to use it like this

```
<g:link mapping="a" params="[file: name]">${name}</g:link>
```

Where **name** could be: *"myfile.pdf"*

Problem is, when I get to my controller, Grails strips the extension, so I get

```
 params.file = "myfile"
```

Where I would like *"myfile.pdf"* to be able to search for the full file name in my domain objects.

I have tried to set

```
 grails.mime.file.extensions = false
```

But then all my controllers using "withFormat" is not working. Is there a way, where I can find the value of the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have

```
 grails.mime.file.extensions = true
```

and using next mapping

```
"/excursion/$path**" {
  controller = "excursion"
  action = "sweet"
}
```

In Controller

```
def path = params.path
    if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(path) && request.format) {
      path += ".${request.format}"
    }
```