# Grails URLMapping deep path

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have a URL like:

```
/test/abs/rdc/tx.js
```

and I need to be able to get the /abs/rdc/tx.js part for my controller.

I tried (in URLMapping):

```
/test/$target**
```

and it returns everything but the .js

I have

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = true
```

Any ideas?

[UrlMapping and file name extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932289/urlmapping-and-file-name-extension) didn't work as it always returns .html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails 2.0 has made some changes to the way the format is parsed.  Using the example from the link you provided, just update the code to use `response.format`:

```
def path = params.path
if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(path) && response.format) {
  path += ".${response.format}"
}
```

More info is in the manual under [Content Negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation).  Scroll down to the section titled **Request format vs. Response format**.

Comment: That is what the "UrlMapping and file name extension" link I provided said to do.  .${response.format} always returns "html", which is incorrect.   I'll check the Content Negotiation link. Thanks

Comment: No, read my response.  `request.format` always returns html, `response.format` returns the correct extension.  Try it — I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
//Grails 2.3.x
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```